# How to find the version of a Maven plugin in the project?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-wagon-plugin

I'm trying to find the version of ***maven-wagon*** plugin that's being used in my project. Is there a way to find the version of a used plugin via command line?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are several ways to do this:

**1) Check the dependency tree:**

To find out the libraries and versions you are using you can use the [Maven dependency tree](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html), just execute this where you have your project (*pom.xml*):

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose
```

This is useful detect which version of an specific library your project is using, but I think it doesn't include plugins.

**2) Describe the specific plugin:**

If you want to know what version of an specific plugin you have installed you can do this:

> mvn -Dplugin=: help:describe
>
> mvn -Dplugin=org.codehaus.mojo:wagon-maven-plugin help:describe

This shows you something like this:

```
Name: Maven Wagon plugin
Description: Maven plugin that can be used to access various operations on a
  given URL using a supported maven wagon. Supports recursive upload, download,
  and list directory content functionality.
Group Id: org.codehaus.mojo
Artifact Id: wagon-maven-plugin
Version: 1.0
Goal Prefix: wagon
 
This plugin has 11 goals:
...
...
```

**3) Check the effective pom:**

Execute this:

> mvn help:effective-pom

and go through the pom looking for the plugin you need to clarify, there you will find something like this:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
   <artifactId>wagon-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately it does not show the version of maven-wagon plugin.

Comment: I just create a dummy project and you're right, but then the first option works for you:
*mvn help:effective-pom*
I just tried it by myself and it showed me the version 1.0, have you tried it?

Comment: Based on your feedback I went back to the answer and re-write it to show more options to get the info you need... hope it works for you phani

Comment: `mvn -Dplugin=org.codehaus.mojo:wagon-maven-plugin help:describe` worked. I don't think this plugin needs to be explicitly defined. That's why it didn't show up in effective pom.